# How can I push a github actions artifact to my pull request

Tags: github-actions, git-push

I am trying to set up a workflow with github actions that automatically compiles latex and images into a pdf file when a pull request is opened, than adds the final product (the pdf) to that pull request.
Normally the procedure is that I do changes into a branch, then open the PR and merge into the master branch.

The pdf file (`doc.pdf`) is correctly generated, and after that it is made available using the `upload-artifact' action. However I can't figure out how to add it to the current PR.

The following sets up git,

```
      - name: git configuration
        run: |
          git config user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"

      - name: git commit/push
        run: |
          git add doc.pdf
          git commit -m "update pdf"
          git push origin
```

but it fails returning the error: `* (HEAD detached at pull/314/merge)`. I don't want to push directly to the master branch (for security reasons this requires approval by a maintainer) and I don't want to change every time the `yml` file to specify the name of the branch I am working on, because the idea of this is that one only modifies the tex files and the pdf is automatically created and made available upon merging to master branch.

If pushing to the open PR is not possible or recommended, what would be an alternative way to achieve the same results?

**EDIT:** following advice by @SM2A I have added `with: ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}` at the checkout action, but it causes git to fail.

The initial part of the `yml` file is this:

```
name: compile_pdf
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths:
       - 'latex/**/*.tex'
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
    paths:
       - 'latex/**/*.tex'

jobs:
  create_pdf:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify this on top of your `yml` file

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
```

The give the runner write permission by adding this to top of your file

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
```

Now a code like this can do the job

```yaml
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
- name: Commit
  run: |
    git config --global user.name 'Bot'
    git config --global user.email '<>'
    git add .
    git commit -m "update pdf"
    git push
```

Comment: thanks @SM2A. This however fails with a `/usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --no-recurse-submodules --depth=2 origin +refs/heads/new_pdf*:refs/remotes/origin/new_pdf* +refs/tags/new_pdf*:refs/tags/new_pdf* The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1` error message. Any idea why?

Comment: maybe a bit more of your `yml` file could help. but in general it's not a difficult task to push into source branch of a pull request

Comment: @point618 Well I tried to simulate your error but I couldn't. The only thing that I think might cause the error is that your project has some submodules and when you try to commit using `origin` keyword confuses git where to push. simply use `git push` and let me know what happens

Comment: It seems the error is in the checkout step, that is what gives the above message. Checking out the repo works fine without `ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}` but crashes otherwise. Changing the fetch-depth has no effect.

Comment: @point618 Is there any uncommited changes before checkout?

Comment: there are, but only on my local machine. I think everything on github is committed. Maybe I am misunderstanding what "trigger on pull request" means?

Comment: @point618 It simply means when is your CI task should run. When you set run on every push, each push to remote repo will trigger the workflow and let it do it's job like build and test the code. But some tasks might not be needed to run on every push like checking code style. In this case you make workflow file trigger on a pull request so that the code is going to merge meet your desired conditions.

Comment: That is what I thought. The issue is definetely with `ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}`. Without it, it runs (but then I can't push because it is a detached HEAD

Comment: @point618 A workflow triggerd on a pull request is a detached HEAD. Thats why you need to checkout to it's source branch. Is your repo private?

Comment: No, the repo is public. I think I figured out the issue. if `ref: ${{ github.ref }}` is used instead of `ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}` then it works. I think that the first one refers to the PR that triggers the workflow, while the second one refers to an existing branch.

Comment: @point618  hope it workedout for you. Other wise you can share your repo